# WPF binding from parent to child element

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

Here is my XAML

```
 <ListView x:Name="missingVariablesListView" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="320" Margin="81,28,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="641" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="ComponentID: " FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Brown" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Parameters}">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel>
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <TextBlock Text="Variable Name: " Foreground="Green"/>
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                                <TextBlock Text="   "/>                                           
                                                <TextBlock Text="Variable Value: " Foreground="Blue"/>
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"/>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                                    <Style >
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMissing}" Value="false">
                                                <Setter Property="UIElement.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>                                                    
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                            </ItemsControl>                           
                                <TextBlock Text="-----------------------------------------------------------------"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

Here is the CodeBehind

```
  this.missingVariablesListView.DataContext = //Code to fill in the list View
```

Classes Involved

```
public class Component
  {
  private ObservableCollection<ComponentParameter> parameters = new ObservableCollection<ComponentParameter>();
  public string Name
  {
    get;
    set;
  }

  public ObservableCollection<ComponentParameter> Parameters
  {
    get{return parameters;}
    set{parameters = value;}
   }
}



 public class ComponentParameter
 {
   public string Name
   {
    get;set;
   }

    public string Value
   {
    get;set;
   }

   public bool HasErrors
   {
    get;
    set;
   }

   public bool IsMissing
   {
    get;set;
   }
```

Sample Output (at the moment)

```
ComponentID: Component1
--------------------------

ComponentID: Component2
VariableName:Var1 Variable Value:Val1
VariableName:Var2 Variable Value:Val2
-----------------------

ComponentID: Component3
-----------------------

ComponentID: Component4
-----------------------
```

What i want to do is that whenever the boolean IsMissing is true for the inner element within the itemsControl i want to make sure that the ComponentID and the Name properties within the StackPanel (that has the orientation as horizontal) are not shown in the window including the child elements. Basically i am trying to find a way to exclude the whole description for that particular ComponentID whose isMissing variable is set to true. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: There may be multiple items in your `ItemsControl`, so which one do you want to check for its `IsMissing` property?

Comment: Hi @Gehho yes there are multiple Items and i want to Check for all items within that ItemsControl. As long as IsMissing is false for all the items i want to exclude them from showing to the user. I only show the items that have isMissing set to true.

Comment: @ elgonzo i am wrapping the object as observationCollection so those things should be done implicitly behind the scenes. Thanks for letting me know

Comment: @Sike: No. ObservableCollection only monitors and notifies about changes to the collection itself. It will not know (and hence neither notify) if and when a property of an object stored in the collection changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider to add a property `IsAnyParameterMissing` to the `Component` class:

```
public class Component
{
    private ObservableCollection<ComponentParameter> parameters = new ObservableCollection<ComponentParameter>();
    public string Name
    {
      get;
      set;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ComponentParameter> Parameters
    {
        get{return parameters;}
        set{parameters = value;}
    }

    public bool IsAnyParameterMissing
    {
        get { return this.Parameters.Any(param => param.IsMissing); }
    }
}
```

And then bind the visibility to this property:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="{Binding IsAnyParameterMissing, Converter={BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
    <TextBlock Text="ComponentID: " FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Brown" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

This will only display the `StackPanel` if any of the `Parameter`s in the collection has its `IsMissing` property equal to `true`. Note that this will not change the visibility if the `IsMissing` property is changed for any of the items! This would need some additional work.

**EDIT:** Note that the `{BooleanToVisibilityConverter}` might need to be adjusted, depending on your available converters. Should be a simple task though.

Comment: yeah this seems to work with the property being outside. Thanks gehho

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` to hide those items for you, although you *may* need to change your property or add a new `IsPresent` property for this:

In `Resources`:

```
<Converters:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter" 
    IsInverted="True" />
```

In your `ListView.ItemTemplate`:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="{Binding IsMissing, Converter={
    StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
    <TextBlock Text="ComponentID: " FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Brown" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Custom `BoolToVisibilityConverter` with `IsInverted` property:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(bool), typeof(Visibility))]
public class BoolToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public bool IsInverted { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null || value.GetType() != typeof(bool)) return null;
        bool boolValue = IsInverted ? !(bool)value : (bool)value;
        return boolValue ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null || value.GetType() != typeof(Visibility)) return null;
        if (IsInverted) return (Visibility)value != Visibility.Visible;
        return (Visibility)value == Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

Now it will just take you one minute to implement it. I have updated the XAML example above to use it.

Comment: @ sheridian .... the converters tag do i reference it like this? xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.WPF.Converters;assembly=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls"

Comment: Sorry @Sike12, I got mixed up between my custom converter and the one that is now included in .NET... you *should* be able to use that converter without adding an XML namespace: <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />

Comment: Cant we do it by Putting IsMissing instead of IsPresent?

Comment: In my custom `BoolToVisibilityConverter`, I have an `IsInverted` property which would allow this, but I don't think that the standard .NET one has this option... so either create a new `IsPresent` property that returns `!IsMissing`, or [implement your own converter](http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html) with an `IsInverted` property.

Comment: But this will not work since the `IsMissing` property is defined on the `ComponentParameter` class and the `DataContext` of the `StackPanel` is an instance of the `Component` class. This does not have an `IsMissing` property! Sike12 wants the `StackPanel` to be invisible if the `IsMissing` property is `true` for _any of the `ComponentParameter` instances_ .

Comment: It will work if he implements a custom `BoolToVisibilityConverter` with an `IsInverted` property like I just suggested in the last comment.

Comment: I can see your point @Sheridian. At the moment i dont think i would want to implement my own converter just for this scenario but yes good solution suggested thanks.

Comment: @Sike12, regardless of your current problem, if you are to continue writing WPF, then you should be building up a large collection of your own custom `Converter` classes anyway. Implementing a `Converter` class only takes a minute and they're a huge part of WPF... it'd be a shame if you missed out on what they have to offer. I've edited my answer to include my `Converter` for your future use.

Comment: @Sheridan But still, the `IsMissing` property is not defined on the `Component` class! So your `Visibility="{Binding IsMissing, Converter=...` will not succeed since there is no `IsMissing` property to bind to. Note that the other Binding within the StackPanel binds to the `Name` property of the `Component`, not the `ComponentParameter` class! The ItemsControl is then bound to the `Parameters` collection. That means, a simple BoolToVis is not sufficient since there are multiple binding sources, i.e. all `ComponentParameter` instances in the `Parameters` collection.

Comment: +1 Ahhhhhh @gehho, I now see what you're saying... I think I read the description but maybe didn't see the code example. Point accepted and thanks for sharing that.

Answer (score 1):

One thing i noticed is that you don't implement the properties (such as "*isMissing*") as **DependencyProperty**. Neither do you use property change notifications via **INotifyPropertyChanged**.

You have to implement either of the two, otherwise changes of the properties will not be propagated through the bindings. That means, the trigger wouldn't trigger...

Comment: @Elogonzo thanks seems like there is somemore work to do. Thanks :)